# ArrayInput doesn't trigger onChange function when I remove item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

I have added an `onChange` property. It works perfectly when I add a new element, but if I remove an element, the function isn't triggered.

```html
<ArrayInput
   source="names"
   label={'Names'}
   onChange={updateNames}
   >
   <SimpleFormIterator   
      className={classes.iteratorFormItem}
      >
      <TextInput
         label=""
         source="value"
         validate={maxLength(MAX)}
         />
   </SimpleFormIterator>
</ArrayInput>
```

I don't understand why `onChange` doesn't trigger when I remove an element, because the array is modified in that case.

Comment: can you please add the complete code or create a sandbox reproducing your use case ?

Comment: I dont have to many code, the updateNames function just print a console.log with the ean list, but just when I add a new value, if a remove a value, it doesnt print anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onChange` isn't a supported prop of react-admin's `<ArrayInput>`. If it works when the user updates a sub-record, it's by accident. The documentation makes no mention of it (see https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#array-inputs).

Now, it seems you want to do thing to the data when it's changed by the user. Why not use the `parse` option instead? (https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#common-input-props).

Comment: Mmm, I just want to handle what happens if there are 3 items and the user remove one of them.

parse looks like more to handle the data when user change. Is there nothing like that?

Comment: parse will catch changes in the data, so you can detect when one of the element was removed there.

Comment: And it ArrayInput doesn't suit your need, you can always replace it with your own component

Comment: it would be good to share with us your solved code @BigBugCreator

Comment: @FrançoisZaninotto I tried to add the parse method but is not being called when the input changes...

<ArrayInput source="worksitebatchsettlementmodifiedworks" parse={parseMethod}>

const parseMethod = (value: any) => {
     console.log('parseMethod', value);
     return value;
}

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a custom remove button just works as expected:

```
const handleRemove = () => {
    console.log('handleRemove');
}



<SimpleFormIterator
    removeButton={
        <RemoveItemButtonWithListener
            listener={handleRemove}
        />
    }
>



import CloseIcon from '@mui/icons-material/RemoveCircleOutline';

const RemoveItemButtonWithListener = (
    props: {
        listener: () => void
    }
) => {
    const { remove } = useSimpleFormIteratorItem();
    return (
        <IconButtonWithTooltip
            label="ra.action.remove"
            size="small"
            onClick={
                () => {
                    remove();
                    props.listener();
                }
            }
            color="warning"
        >
            <CloseIcon fontSize="small" />
        </IconButtonWithTooltip>
    );
};
```